Gradient of field computed using FEM (L2 Projection)
From my understanding, in the finite element context, an L2 projection can be formulated as the following linear system:
$$
M\ \phi = \beta
$$
where $M$ is the mass matrix, $\phi$ the resulting projection, and $\beta$ is computed as:
$$
\beta_i = \int_V N_i u\ dV 
$$
where u is the function to be projected. If $u$ is the gradient of a field $U$ computed using FEM, then it seems to me that the above integral, for the 1D case, is expressed as:
$$
\beta_i = \int_V N_i \frac{dU}{dx} \ dV = \int_V N_i \sum_j^{N_{nodes}} \frac{dN_j}{dx}U_j dV
$$
Is my logic here correct? Although this approach seemed to work for me in 1D, it fails to produce a physical result in 2D.

Perhaps it would be helpful for us readers if you could also outline the 2D case.

Thank you for your interest @ConvexHull. I found out that it was actually more of a visualization issue. The approach works pretty much the same.
